# Twitter Bootstrap does not resize(well) on mobiles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Twitter Bootstrap on two project, one is a static HTML website and other is a Rails application. When I test the website on desktop browser,resize works. But when I test it on mobile [Nokia E72], it just does not fit the width. Interesting thing is when I test the bootstrap homepage (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) - it also has same problem.. Is this only me? I searched on stackoverflow and Google and everyone else seems to pretty happy with Bootstrap on their mobiles.

I have also tested alternative framework: Foundation - which seems to work better and there is at least no horizontal scroll.

Update: This seems to be a problem on my nokia E72.

Comment: What browser are you using on your Nokia E72? Try it with Opera Mini. The more popular the browser, the better it will work with bootstrap. On my Android phone the bootstrap site and my own sites work perfectly, and there are no horizontal scroll bars visible. I used both the Android native browser and Chrome.

Comment: @IvoBosticky +1. I am using the default browser. I checked the website on responsinator.com as posted in below answer and it looks great. It seems it is the issue mentioned by you. Can you post this as an answer. Also, do you think there is some way to support default browser of Nokia E72.

Comment: You could always submit an issue with the Bootstrap developers at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues?state=open asking for Nokia browser support.

Comment: I have also a Nokia, another old model, and I have the same problem in Opera Mini when using bootstrap. When rendering the site, the width is not reaching the device's max width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more popular the browser, the better it will work with bootstrap. Quoting bootstrap documentation

> Originally built with only modern browsers in mind, Bootstrap has evolved to include support for all major browsers (even IE7!) and, with Bootstrap 2, tablets and smartphones, too.

The Nokia E72 native browser is probably not supported and not standards compliant. You could try testing with Opera Mini. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers the Nokia browser has a usage share of anywhere between 0.3% and 12% in 2011, and the trend appears to be that it's loosing marker share. So you should really test with Safari, Opera and Android.

Answer (score 6):

Twitter's bootstrap only supports desktop browsers it seems.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Browser-Compatibility

Ok, I just found out there's something you need to add for android resizing:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

From http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: I had this in my website, it renders fine in Android (Chrome) in a Sony Xperia. But in Opera Mini in this Nokia is not fitting the width.

Comment: Adding the meta tag worked for me, solved a huge headache, thanks man! : )

Comment: Note: the decimal `initial-scale=1.0` is important. You can't leave it at just `1`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with your phone (or it's screen size), but you might find the following site very helpful in testing your website... http://www.responsinator.com/ - you will probably find your screen size and that may help resolve the issue.